Multiple data types in the object part of a Dictionary<string, object>
I need to send this object through a CMS API into the controller:
{
    "configData":[{"filename":"tttttttt"},{"year":"2024"},{"month":"03"}],
    "unitData":[{"a":0,"b":1,"c":"asd"},{"a":0,"b":1,"c":"dsa"}]
}

Then the controller:
public string createAuditRels([FromBody] Dictionary<string,object> apiData)
{
    var apiConfigData = apiData["configData"] as Dictionary<string,string>;
    var filename = apiConfigData["filename"];
    ...
}

But I'm getting an error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is this data structure possible (multiple data types in the objects type)?

From your request body, your configData is an array, so you cast it to Dictionary<string,string> type will return you null as different type.

Your configData is an array of objects but not an object. So you will get null when you are trying to cast to Dictionary<string, string>.
Cast it as List<Dictionary<string, string>> type.
var apiConfigData = apiData["configData"] as List<Dictionary<string, string>>;
var filename = apiConfigData[0]["filename"];

Alternative, you can create a model class for your request body.
public class AuditRelModel
{
    public List<ConfigDataModel> ConfigData { get; set; }
    public List<UnitDataModel> UnitData { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigDataModel
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
}

public class UnitDataModel
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}

public string createAuditRels([FromBody] AuditRelModel apiData)
{
    var filename = apiData.ConfigData[0].Filename;
}


Generates this apiData
{"ConfigData":[{"Filename":"2024_3","Year":null,"Month":null},{"Filename":null,"Year":"2024","Month":null},{"Filename":null,"Year":null,"Month":"03"}]}"
So it will always depend on the array position to get a specific value.
